# Can I encode and decode a NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, nscoding

I was wondering if I can I use encode/decode with an NSManagedObject. Can I use that or I need a NSObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does't make a lot of sense to do so. Technically you can implement the methods, but you need to think carefully about what they do. You could use them to create a binary representation of the object, but it might not be meaningful for what you want to use it for. And, when reading that data back in, you could implement it to search some context and return an existing object or insert a new one if it's missing. You have the problem of supplying the context to be used to deal with...

So, while you might be able to do it, it probably isn't the correct approach to be taking.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to vote and tick answers that help and solve your problem :-)